# OptionSet subclass - is it possible

Tags: swift, bitmask, optionsettype

I would like to subclass a `class` that is implementing `OptionSet`, so that I can add some additional `options` only for this `subclass`. Is this possible? I tried something like this:

```
extension AugmentedRealityViewSceneKit {

    public class EngineConfiguration: OptionSet {

        public static let enableSun   = EngineConfiguration(rawValue: 1 << 0)
        public static let enableFloor = EngineConfiguration(rawValue: 1 << 1)

        public var rawValue: Int

        required public init(rawValue: RawValue) {
            self.rawValue = rawValue
        }

    }

}

extension AugmentedRealityViewARKit {

    public class EngineConfiguration: AugmentedRealityViewSceneKit.EngineConfiguration {

        public static let enableWorldTracking              = EngineConfiguration(rawValue: 1 << 2)
        public static let enableEnvironmentLightEstimation = EngineConfiguration(rawValue: 1 << 3)
        public static let enableFloorLevelDetection        = EngineConfiguration(rawValue: 1 << 4)

    }
}
```

But this doesn't work when I try to check if option is in given set using `.contains()` - it shows:

> 'AugmentedRealityViewARKit.EngineConfiguration' requires the types
>   'AugmentedRealityViewARKit.EngineConfiguration' and
>   'AugmentedRealityViewSceneKit.EngineConfiguration' be equivalent to
>   use 'contains'

Example playground:

```
import UIKit

public class EngineConfigurationA: OptionSet {

    public static let enableSun   = EngineConfigurationA(rawValue: 1 << 0)
    public static let enableFloor = EngineConfigurationA(rawValue: 1 << 1)

    public var rawValue: Int

    required public init(rawValue: RawValue) {
        self.rawValue = rawValue
    }

}


public class EngineConfigurationB: EngineConfigurationA {

    public static let enableWorldTracking              = EngineConfigurationB(rawValue: 1 << 2)
    public static let enableEnvironmentLightEstimation = EngineConfigurationB(rawValue: 1 << 3)
    public static let enableFloorLevelDetection        = EngineConfigurationB(rawValue: 1 << 4)

}

let optionsB: EngineConfigurationB = [EngineConfigurationB.enableWorldTracking, EngineConfigurationA.enableSun]

let contains = optionsB.contains(EngineConfigurationB.enableWorldTracking)
```

Comment: Interesting – I would have expected the compiler to upcast `optionsB` to `EngineConfigurationA` in order to make the call (it works if you insert a coercion yourself). You can essentially boil down the example to this: https://gist.github.com/hamishknight/a0655f40f85c675c6f75ac57cdaa2b90, which yields the amusingly incorrect error message "'B' is not convertible to 'A'". I'm not sure whether or not the compiler is supposed to support this, but I'll file a bug anyway in a bit.

Comment: Bug filed: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-9037

Comment: I can't even make this compile. I get errors like `method 'union' in non-final class 'EngineConfigurationA' must return `Self` to conform to protocol 'SetAlgebra'` for `union`, `intersection`, `symmetricDifference` and `subtracting`. The compiler isn't happy that it's possible for subclasses to override these methods to return a subclass instance, rather than `Self` (the superclass)